# Create a java program that prompt the user for a positive number and then displays each digit in reverse order on a separate line

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Digitsdisplay {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");

    int value = input.nextInt();
    int total  = 0;
    String digit = "" + value;

    System.out.print("");

    for (int i = 0; i < digit.length(); i++) {
       int myInt = Integer.parseInt(digit.substring(i, i + 1));
       System.out.println(myInt);
       total += myInt;
    }

}
}
```

output:
Please enter a value: 
**789**
7
8
9

How do I reverse the output? For example, when I enter the number 123, it would display 321 with each digit on a new line.

Comment: Go through the loop in reverse direction.

Comment: (Also, there's a way to do it without using `String`s)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply reverse the string before looping through it

```
digit = new StringBuilder(digit).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: There is no reason to reverse the string before looping. It is better to just loop backwards performance wise.

Comment: I felt that the answer the asker was looking for relied more in simplicity than performance issues. I my self would have taken I completely different approach, as Dennis Meng, might also have pointed out.

Comment: But adding an extra call to reverse the string is not more simple than just looping in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is inputting values in base 10, you could instead use the modulo operator along with integer division to grab the rightmost values successively in a while loop as so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Digitsdisplay {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");

        int value = input.nextInt();
        int quotient = value;
        int remainder = 0;

        while(quotient != 0){
            remainder = quotient%10;
            quotient = quotient/10;
            System.out.print(remainder);
        }

    }
}
```

This might be a better method that attempting to convert the int to a string and then looping through the string character by character.

Answer (score 0):

Loop you printing for loop in the reverse direction:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Digitsdisplay {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");

        int value = input.nextInt();
        int total  = 0;
        String digit = "" + value;

        System.out.print("");

        for (int i = digit.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
           int myInt = Integer.parseInt(digit.substring(i, i + 1));
           System.out.println(myInt);
           total += myInt;
        }

    }
}
```

Edit: No reason to reverse the string itself, ie. using a Stringbuilder like the other answers say. This just adds to the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Francis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
         System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");

    int value = input.nextInt();
    int total  = 0;
    String digit = "" + value;

    System.out.print("");

    for (int i = 0; i < digit.length(); i++) {
       int myInt = Integer.parseInt(digit.substring(i, i + 1));
       System.out.println(myInt);
       total += myInt;
    }
  }
}
```